# IpadOS connect lightning to hdmi and usb together

Tags: ipad, usb, hdmi, lightning

I've got the ipad mini 5th generation. I want to connect it to my monitor, it has usb-c/hdmi ports, also I want to use my usb devices, I've done this with apple tv, but picture is not so good on 4k monitor, and i think about some wired solution, I've got adapters: lightning to usb, lightning to type-c (But it doesn't show picture on my type c monitor) is there any way to use usb+hdmi via lightning together? (maybe some wireless hubs or something else?..maybe someone has a good idea to do it? I think it'll be helpful to a lot of people.

Comment: is this your device? https://www.gsmarena.com/apple_ipad_mini_(2019)-9637.php

Comment: Yes, this is my device.

Answer (score 3):

So, if I understand right you have basically two set of questions:

**1. can an iPad Mini (5th generation) be connected to a 4k monitor? if so, how? and what can I expect in terms of image quality/resolution?**

Yes, it is possible to connect a lightning-iDevice to a HDMI-Display using a [Lightning Digital AV Adapter](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/md826am/a/lightning-digital-av-adapter). It will mirror your display. The iPad Mini 5Gen has "1536 x 2048 pixels, 4:3 ratio" and that is what you will see in your 4k-Monitor. (for reference check this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0sifF94l3Kw))

**2. given that the connction iPadMini-Display is working, can I have more USB devices attached?**

Unfortunately, no. And [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_BASZ5BCEmw) is a video that shows it ^^
I really doubt there is a way to map the [Lightning-pins](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/bb/Lightning_pins.png) to [HDMI-pins](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/48/HDMI_Connector_Pinout.svg/1920px-HDMI_Connector_Pinout.svg.png) AND to the [USB2.0-pins](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/66/USB_Type-A.svg/1280px-USB_Type-A.svg.png) simultnaeously
... if you had in mind to use a mouse or a keyboard, may be you could achieve that over a Bluetooth connection.

---

Side questions:
**Why is my lightning to type-C-USB connection not showing any picture?**
This is because of the diversitiy in protocols/standards. [Lightning](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/bb/Lightning_pins.png) on that iDevice, in terms of USB is essentially [USB2.0](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/66/USB_Type-A.svg/1280px-USB_Type-A.svg.png) and this USB standard does not support video/image transmission. The standard that supports that is a [USB-C alternate mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB-C#Alternate_Mode_partner_specifications) which, at least, requires [USB-C](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a5/USB_Type-C.svg/1280px-USB_Type-C.svg.png) on both sides. (you only have one, on your display...)